# How to expand space available on disk

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage

When I was installing Ubuntu I used this guide to do the partition manually: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)
When I run `sudo lsblk` I have this partition scheme:

```
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                       LABEL
... a lot of snap patitions ...
...
sda             223,6G                                  
├─sda1 ntfs       450M                                  Recovery/restore (translation)
├─sda2 vfat       100M                                  
├─sda3             16M                                  
├─sda4 swap       488M [SWAP]                           
├─sda5 ext4      18,6G /                                
├─sda6 ext4     195,6G /home                            
└─sda7             95M
```

I thought it's okay, but lately ubuntu started to show me the message that "there's only 1gb left". When I'm checking it in the file explorer I see this picture:

```
On this computer:
Computer 800MB/ 19.5GB available/

Networks
Windows network
```

So my main question is how do I add more space so it won't be 19.5 gb only but all the other space left that I thought I used. What's the correct way to distribute all the space available here in the partitions? Should I made the "/" partition more, how much do I need to left for the "/home" then and how do I do it? Is space available for "/" will be available for "/home" too?

And the second question (unnecessary to answer since Ubuntu seems to work okay, but still) did windows left something on the hard drive, since I see "Windows network"? Because I was installing Ubuntu when I already had Windows, I removed the windows partition and made other steps as described in the guide I linked.

Comment: Not really, I edited the question

Comment: So what is the problem? You made `/` too small, now you can enlarge it. Also when you run gparted, you'll see what Windows partitions you have. You didn't ask for anything else.

Comment: If you want to use all the space, you don't make a separate partition for `/`. You did that for some reason and now  you have a problem.

Comment: How much should I left for the home then?

Comment: There is no answer for that. All your personal files are stored in `/home`.

Comment: I understand, I mean in this situation, is space available for "/" will be available for "/home" too? I edited the question.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The space will be allocated either to `/` or to `/home`. That's the whole point of having separate partitions. It was a mistake to follow some manual without understanding of the concept.

Comment: So add something to `/` from `/home` and that will solve the issue.

Comment: And in order to do the wise suggestion above you'll need to shrink /home, "move it to the right" so the new unallocated space appears after the end of / and finally expand / into that unallocated space. Any of this operations has variable risks of data loss. Do your backups before, of course.